# Robot Frame work response timeout

Tags: python, robotframework

Need input on robot framework  response timeout,

By default robot frame gets timed by 3sec.

Is there any way to increase the response time from 3sec(default) to 10 seconds.

Thanks,
Vignesh

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Did you google, read documentation and tried to find an answer? What did you find and what could you not?

Comment: used "Set timeout" from telnet module but it is not taking any effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

| Library | Telnet | 30 Seconds

This Command will overwrite default timeout of 3 seconds